# How do I query array elements in elastic search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

This is the index of my model in the elastic search

```
 {  
       "_index":"cars",
       "_type":"car",
       "_id":"3275",
       "_version":4,
       "_score":1,
       "_source":{  
         "category_id": 6,
          "car_branches":[  
             {  
                "id":32,
                "name":"Type1"
             },
             {  
                "id":33,
                "name":"Type2"
             },
             {  
                "id":36,
                "name":"Type3"
             }
          ],

       }
    }
```

I can query category_id with

`Car.__elasticsearch__.search query:{match:{category_id: 6}}`

How do I query for car_branches? I tried this

`response = Car.__elasticsearch__.search query:{match:{car_branches:[id: 32]}}`

I am getting `Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400]`

Comment: What is the mapping of the `car_branches` field? Run this `curl -XGET localhost:9200/cars/_mapping/car` and update your question with the output you get.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e90d5c881635f682f3a25b5235dcf91a @Val

Comment: Can you show your mapping definition of your cars model (in ruby)?

Comment: I can't understand you .. can you explain please

Comment: How does your `Car` ruby model look like?

Comment: It is just like a normal model, and it is working fine with category_id search, Just wanted to know how to query for key values inside arrays.. I am sorry there is no car, it's different, I am just making up own Car for a similar model I have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128221/discussion-between-gates-and-val).

Answer (score 0):

You first need to delete your index first and recreate it. Before doing so, you need to change your mapping and make the `car_branches` field `nested`, like this:

```
  indexes :car_branches, type: 'nested' do
      indexes :id
      indexes :name
```

Then you'll be able to make the query your want like this:

```
response = Car.__elasticsearch__.search query:{nested:{path: 'car_branches', query:{term:{'car_branches.id':[32]}}}}
```

Comment: Mapping like this 
```def as_indexed_json(options={})
      as_json(
        only: [:category_id],
        include: {
          car_branches: {only: [:id, :name]}
          }
      )
    end```